# Word 2007 document property field "Update Field" changes metadata, not display

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, properties, field-codes

To get the word "Author" document property you would normally enter Ctrl+F9 and type "DOCPROPERTY Author".

```
{ DOCPROPERTY Author }
```

In the particular instance I am dealing with, the code has been entered

```
{ AUTHOR "Frank Miller" }
```

The difference in behaviour (both 2007 and 2010) is that when edit the Author property then right click and choose "Update Field" on the first instance, the display is changed to the new Author.
In the second, the document property is instead changed to "Frank Miller".

Is assume this a designed feature, if so is there any documentation on this? 
What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you're displaying the value of the Author property.

In your second example, you're assigning the value "Frank Miller" to the Author property.

You can see this by performing an "Update Field" on the first example after doing an "Update Field" on the second example - the first example will now display "Frank Miller" or whatever value you have assigned in the second example.

So, this is the expected behavior.

You can find more information here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-author-field-HA102014624.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102110133